# ¿Cual es el siguiente paso al tener una app de flask lista?

Tags: python, flask

Tengo mi pagina lista pero siempre tengo que ir al directorio en la consola y ejecutar "python app.py", mi objetivo es hacer una app personal que me muestre unas estadisticas de una base de datos. Queria saber si hay una manera de ejecutarla como un programa o desde el navegador tipo ir a un marcador y que se inice sola la app, es eso posible? me gustaria saber esto para conocer todo el proceso de trabajo

Comment: En [la documentación de Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/#deployment) tenes las diferentes opciones. Si querés hacer un programa podrías usar PyQt en lugar de Flask. También te puede servir Pyinstaller.

Comment: Es para principalmente mostrar la documentacion de manera dinamica. Si hago un programa cada vez que vaya a abrir la documentacion especifica de una funcion esta tendria que abrir una ventana, si lo hago en pdf no tendria el dinamismo de verificar siempre la cantidad de codigos de la libreria en tiempo real sino cad vez que se ejecutara, por eso lo del explorador y la pregunta